# JQuery Sortable\Serialize issue

Tags: jquery-ui, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a document that uses PHP to generate a list from a DB

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM display ORDER BY diplay_order ASC";
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

echo "<ul id='categoryorder'>";

while ($item = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

echo "<li><div id='" . $item['ad_type'] . "_" . $item['unique_id'] . "'>
      <form name='remove' action='saveable.php' method='get'>
      <input type='submit' value='remove' />
      <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $item['unique_id'] . "'>
      </form>" .$item['unique_id'] . "</div></li>";     
}

echo "</ul>";
```

I have then made these sortable which works fine but I can't get the serialize to work and it just creates an empty array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {                             
   $('ul#categoryorder').sortable({ 
    update: function() {
        var order = $("ul#categoryorder").sortable("serialize");
        alert(order);
    }                                         
});
});
```

Then the alert box just comes up empty. I am very new to this and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `id` to `<li>` tag. Change this part of PHP code,

```
echo "<li id='" . $item['ad_type'] . "_" . $item['unique_id'] . "'><div><form name='remove' action='saveable.php' method='get'><input type='submit' value='remove' /><input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $item['unique_id'] . "'></form>" .$item['unique_id'] . "</div></li>";
```

Added `id` to `<li>`.